# Attributed null values to each ID in Athena (Presto)

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Here is what my initial dataset looks like

```
prof_id id title
1       5  A
1       5  B
1       5  C
1       5  D
2       5  C
2       5  D
2       5  E
NA      5  F 
NA      5  G
```

Here is what the new table should look like:

```
prof_id id title
1       5  A
1       5  B
1       5  C
1       5  D
1       5  F
1       5  G
2       5  C
2       5  D
2       5  E
2       5  F 
2       5  G
```

Any row with a null value for a `prof_id` should be attributed to all of the `prof_id`. I have provided an example where there are two '
`prof_id` but there are also instances where there are 1 or 0 `prof_id`.

- For 1, all of the null should be attributed to that single `prof_id`
- For 0, leave it as is

I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure how to start. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How does `id` fit into this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to do cross join, where essentially it is going to multiply 2 tables together.

First to pick out all nulls:

```
select id, title from table where prof_id is null
```

Then pick out the prof_id you want to apply to all tables

```
select distinct prof_id from table where prof_is is not null
```

Do a cross join together, then union the rest of "good" data back

```
(select distinct prof_id from table where prof_is is not null)
CROSS JOIN
(select id, title from table where prof_id is null)

UNION ALL

(select prof_id, id, title from table where prof_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows using a `cross join`.  Then use `union all` to combine this with the rest of the data.

The following syntax should work:

```
select p.prof_id, i.id, t.title
from (select distinct prof_id
      from t
      where prof_id <> 'NA'  -- or do you mean is not null
     ) p cross join
     (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct title
      from t
      where prof_id = 'NA'   -- or is null
     ) t
union all
select prof_id, id, title
from t
where prof_id <> 'NA'        -- or is not null
```